# If clause within if clause VBA Arcgis10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, loop

I'm using ArcGIS10. I do not know what's wrong with this **VBA code** in the Field Calculator:

*All the fields are String type

```
If [StartY]  <  [EndY]  Then
  If [DOT_OSM] ="1" Then
    Output = "F"
  Else
    Output = "T"
  End if
Else if
 If [DOT_OSM] ="1" Then
    Output = "T"
  Else
    Output = "F"
  End if
End If
```

[image: Field calculator]

The Error from ArcGIS: "Syntax error"

Comment: I usually go with Python, but I suspect VB is the same; one string can't be *larger* than another. That is, you can't compare them as you try to in your  If  statement. That would require any numbers format on your field. You can do the = comparison though, but it won't be true until you compare to a text string, e.g.  '1' . I also suspect you need to call your prelogic script in the lower box somehow?

Comment: @juasmilla, Are you open to using python instead of VBS?

Comment: Yes @artwork21 I could do it with Python code instead. Maybe I could try what Martin says.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python version of this would look like:

```
def compare(sY,eY,osm):
  if float(sY) < float(eY):
    if osm == "1":
      return "F"
    else: return "T"
  else:
    if osm == "1":
      return "T"
    else: return "F"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually Python also, and unless you have the VBA extension installed you're using VBScript, not VBA, but more relevantly

```
Else if
 If [DOT_OSM] ="1" Then
```

Else if what? You may want a simple Else here.

Comment: You should also declare the variable output, the very first line should be "Dim output" (but no quotes).